# Is my Angular code for correct? (event binding)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

app.component.html

```html
<input (keypress)="degistir($event)" />
<div> {{isim}} </div>
```

app.component.ts

```ts
isim: string = "";

degistir(event:any){
  this.isim = event.target.value;
}
```

Preview:

[image: Preview of the code as a GIF]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, but whether it is right or wrong depends on how explicit you want your code to be. My code below works as fine as yours but it is more explicit.

```
<input (keypress) = "degistir($event)" />
<div> {{isim}} </div>


public isim: any; //converted to 'any' type because we don't know user input

degistir(event: KeyboardEvent): void { // typeof event is 'KeyboardEvent' and function is type of void
  this.isim = event.target.value;
}
```

Comment: my code is working fine but missing one letter writes. why

Comment: Marking the `isim` variable as `public` is not necessary here as your component wouldn't be usable outside of Angular anyways.

Comment: What is the difference between keyup and keypress?

Comment: **keypress** – fires when a key is pressed down,

**keyup** – fires after any key is released

Comment: `keypress` events are fired before the new character is added to the input.

So the first `keypress` event is fired before the first character is added, while the input is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can write more type safe code

```
   degistir(event:KeyboardEvent){
         this.isim = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
    }
```

or if you want to check each key pressed you can use the following code snippet

```
 degistir(event:KeyboardEvent){
     this.isim = event.key; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be correct.

```
<input (keypress) = "degistir($event)" />
<div> {{isim}} </div>
```

```
isim: string ="";

degistir(event: KeyboardEvent){
this.isim= event.target.value;
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:15:29 - error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

15     this.isim= event.target.value;
                               ~~~~~

Comment: `<input (keyup) = "degistir($event.target.value)" />`
`degistir(event: KeyboardEvent): void  { this.isim = event;}`